# The following model validation gives a unexpected tINTEGER weeoe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
class Walk < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,         length: {minimum 5,    maximum 255}
  validates :description,  length: {minimum 10,   maximum 1000} 
end
```

And cant figure out what is wrong.  Its Rails 5.2.2.1. Error is

/home/ben/malmesburyonline/malmesburyonline/app/models/walk.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting do or '{' or '(' ...ame, length: {minimum 5, maximum 255} ... ^ /home/ben/malmesburyonline/malmesburyonline/app/models/walk.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting do or '{' or '(' ...scription, length: {minimum 10, maximum 1000} ... ^~

Comment: you should change the title, migration is completely irrelevant here. its just a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

you have a syntax error.

`length: {minimum 5,    maximum 255}`

should be

`length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 255}`

Same for the other line.